# Add color to cell background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am fetching data using PHP from MySQL Database. I have a field called outstanding dues, i want that if the outstanding dues are above 0, then the table should display this value with its cell border color as RED. Now, i trying to use a condition but it can't seem to work. I also tried doing this using JQuery Filter method, but still no luck, below is my code for JQuery

```
echo '<div class="middle"><td><center>'. $row['outstandingdues'] . '</center></td></div>';
```

The JQuery method i used for this is as under;

```
<script>
    $( "div" )
    .filter( ".middle" )
    .css( "border-color", "red" );
</script>
```

Comment: `<td>` elements should not be wrapped in a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` can't be a parent of `td`, `td` should be added to a `tr` so give the class to the `td`. `tr` is the only [permitted parent of td](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/td.html#td-context)

```
echo '<td class="middle"><center>'. $row['outstandingdues'] . '</center></td>';
```

then in style

```
td.middle {
    border-color: red
}
```

or in script

```
$("td.middle").css("border-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

addition to Arun P Johny's answer:

```
<?php
$class_middle = "";
if($row['outstandingdues'] > 0) {
    $class_middle = 'class="middle"';
} else {
    $class_middle = "";
}
echo '<td '.$class_middle.'><center>'. $row['outstandingdues'] . '</center></td>';
?>
```

This will make it red only when outstanding dues are greater than 0.

Comment: Already did that part but thanks very much, man! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (by the way do not use div inside your tr tag use it in td or assign .middle class to the td and remove div tag before that td

```
$(function() {

         $( "div.middle" ).css( "background-color", "red"); 

    });
```